# idxmax() doesn't work on SeriesGroupBy that contains NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
income = DataFrame({'name': ['Adam', 'Bill', 'Chris', 'Dave', 'Edison', 'Frank'],
                    'age': [22, 24, 31, 45, 51, 55],
                    'income': [1000, 2500, 1200, 1500, 1300, 1600],
                    })
ageBin = pd.cut(income.age, [20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
grouped = income.groupby([ageBin])
highestIncome = income.ix[grouped.income.idxmax()]
```

I have a DataFrame that contains names, ages and income as follows:

```
index   age income  name
0   22  1000    Adam
1   24  2500    Bill
2   31  1200    Chris
3   45  1500    Dave
4   51  1300    Edison
5   55  1600    Frank
```

I would like to group the data by the age bins and collect the records with highest income. The code above works and the `highestIncome` is:

```
index   age income  name
1   24  2500    Bill
2   31  1200    Chris
3   45  1500    Dave
5   55  1600    Frank
```

However, if I delete the record of Chris and thus there is no record within the age range of *(30, 40]*, I get a `ValueError` at `grouped.income.idxmax()`. I think this is because of the `NaN` in grouped, but I cannot find a way to solve the problem. Any input is appreciated.

**Update:** Thanks a lot for the answers. I do believe this is a bug on idxmax() for groupby objects. I would like to go with the `agg(lambda x: x.idxmax())` approach as I did a test of the speed of using `sort()` vs `agg(lambda x: x.idxmax()` on a 10 million synthetic data set. Here is the code and the output:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

testData = DataFrame({'key': np.random.randn(10000000),
                      'value': np.random.randn(10000000)})
keyBin = pd.cut(testData.key, 1000)

start = time.time()
grouped1 = testData.sort('value', ascending=False).groupby([keyBin])
highestValues1 = testData.ix[grouped1.head(1).index]
end = time.time()
print end - start

start = time.time()
grouped2 = testData.groupby([keyBin])
highestValues2 = testData.ix[grouped2.value.agg(lambda x: x.idxmax())].dropna(how='all')
end = time.time()
print end - start
#validation
(highestValues1.sort() == highestValues2.sort()).all()
```

Output:

```
5.30953717232
1.0279238224

Out[47]:

key      True
value    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: As this seems a bug, I opened an issue about this here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10694. Workaround for now is indeed using `.agg(lambda x: x.idxmax())` instead of using `.idxmax()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting it on github!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grouped['income'].agg(lambda x : x.idxmax())


Out[]:
age
(20, 30]     1
(30, 40]   NaN
(40, 50]     2
(50, 60]     4
Name: income, dtype: float64
```

and then you can do the following to get the data

```
income.ix[result.values].dropna()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `groupby` preserves order of rows within each group, you sort `income` before `groupby`. Then, pick up the firsts using `head`:

```
grouped=income.sort('income', ascending=False).groupby([ageBin])
highestIncome = income.ix[grouped.head(1).index]
#highestIncome is no longer ordered by age. 
#If you want to recover this, sort it again.
highestIncome.sort('age', inplace=True)
```

By the way, beware that the reference manual does not mention that `groupby` will preserve the order. I think most clean solution would be fix pandas's `idxmax` to work. For me, it is a little bit strange why `idxmax` does not work while `max` works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But is sort() expected to take much longer than just finding the max? I will generate a big synthesized data set (with no NaN in groupby just for the sake of the experiment) to test sort() vs idxmax. I will try to update the results tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, it takes longer although I am not sure it will be **much**. Sorting is O(N log N) and finding max is O(N). Practically, your dataset is too large to fit in your memory, it will not be a big deal; sorting millions rows takes a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I did a small test of the two approaches and posted the results in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a lambda function on the groups like so:

```
grouped.apply(lambda x: x.max())
```

Comment: I need to get the index of the max value so that I can still preserve the names.

Comment: This should return a full DataFrame that includes the names and ages of the people.  If you really need the index, just create a new column that copies the original index and my code will return it with everything else.

Comment: The full DataFrame includes all the maximum data on each column. My example happens to make people with names that come later in the alphabetical orders have higher income, which makes this approach work. However, if you just switch 'Frank' and 'Edison' in the name column, you can see the results are not correct.