# Pandas idxmax() doesn't work on Series grouped by time periods which contain NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series that contains scalar values indexes by days over several years. For some years there are not data.

```
2014-10-07    5036.883410
2013-10-11    5007.515654
2013-10-27    5020.184053
2014-09-12    5082.379630
2014-10-14    5032.669801
2014-10-30    5033.276159
2016-10-03    5046.921912
2016-10-19    5141.861889
2017-10-06    5266.138810
```

From this I want to get
1. the maximum for each year
2. the day of the maximum for each year
For those years where there are not data, there should be a nan.

To resolve 1. the following works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data= pd.Series( index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2014-10-07', '2013-10-11', '2013-10-27', '2014-09-12', '2014-10-14', '2014-10-30', '2016-10-03', '2016-10-19', '2017-10-06'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None), data=np.array([5036.88341035, 5007.51565355, 5020.18405295, 5082.37963023, 5032.66980146, 5033.27615931, 5046.92191246, 5141.86188915, 5266.1388102 ]))

# get maximum of each year  
data.resample('A').max()
```

However, I tried different options to get the index of the date with the maximum, but they all failed:

```
data.resample('A').idxmax()
```

This raises the following Attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'idxmax'
```

Then I tried the following:

```
data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('A')).idxmax()
```

but this gave an ValueError without specification.
I then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690493/idxmax-doesnt-work-on-seriesgroupby-that-contains-nan) workaround:

```
data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('A')).agg( lambda x : x.idxmax() )
```

but I did not wore either for temporally grouped data:

```
ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence
```

Apparently the reported [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10694) has not been fixed yet and the suggested workaround for categorical data does not seem to work for temporally grouped/resampled data.

Can anyone provide a suitable workaround for this case or maybe an entirely different (and efficient) solution approach to the above problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you have no records during 2015, but a time period for 2015 is created since it is inside your years' range. You need to manually process this case:

```
data.resample('A').agg(
    lambda x : np.nan if x.count() == 0 else x.idxmax()
)
```

Output:

```
time
2013-12-31   2013-10-27
2014-12-31   2014-09-12
2015-12-31          NaT
2016-12-31   2016-10-19
2017-12-31   2017-10-06
Freq: A-DEC, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly! I was aware of the missing data for 2015, but it also worked for applying, e.g. max() on the resampled data. Despite this I would consider it more a workaround and applying idxmax() directly on the resampled data should give the same output, as it does for max(). Thanks again!