# Python groupby agg multiple columns according to one column

Tags: python

I have this df and I want to groupby ***value_to_groupby*** and get all rest of the columns according to minimal ***value_to_agg_upon***

example:

```
   value_to_groupby  value_to_agg_upon  value_to_copy
0         1                  "0"           "a"
1         1                  "1"           "b"
2         1                  "2"           "c"
3         2                  "5"           "d"
4         2                  "4"           "e"
```

wanted result:

```
    value_to_agg_upon  value_to_copy
1        "0"                  "a"
2        "4"                  "e"
```

trying:

```
df.groupby("value_to_groupby").agg({"value_to_agg_upon": min})
```

gives this:

```
    value_to_agg_upon
1        "0" 
2        "4"
```

Comment: is it necessary to get your wanted result through a groupby? There is an easier way.

Comment: The answer I posted will solve your problem. If it helps accept it as an answer by clicking on tick.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
df.iloc[df.groupby("value_to_groupby")["value_to_agg_upon"].idxmin(), 1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
   value_to_agg_upon value_to_copy
0                  0           "a"
1                  4           "e"
```

---

```
df.iloc[df.groupby("value_to_groupby")["value_to_agg_upon"].idxmin(), :].set_index('value_to_groupby')
```

```
                  value_to_agg_upon value_to_copy                                                                       
value_to_groupby                                                                                                        
1                                 0           "a"                                                                       
2                                 4           "e"
```

### Edit:

add this (convert string containing number to int) :

```
import ast

df['value_to_agg_upon'] = df['value_to_agg_upon'].apply(ast.literal_eval).astype(int)
```

OR

```
df['value_to_agg_upon'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value_to_agg_upon'], errors='ignore')
```

Note: apply make the code slow.

Comment: idxmin() returns ValueError. python 3.7.3

Comment: which pandas version are you using?

Comment: pandas version '0.24.2'

Comment: I am using '1.0.5' version

Comment: Are you using the code on some other data than this? there may be nan values that's why you are getting this. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690493/idxmax-doesnt-work-on-seriesgroupby-that-contains-nan

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
pd.merge(df,df.groupby('value_to_groupby').min('value_to_agg_upon'),on=['value_to_groupby','value_to_agg_upon'])
```

Output

```
   value_to_groupby  value_to_agg_upon value_to_copy
0                 1                  0             a
1                 2                  4             e
```

Answer (score 0):

** I previously posted a Wrong answer.**

Since the data is object/string type.

one smart thing to do is (using the answer provided by pygirl) :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"value_to_groupby":[1,1,1,2,2],
"value_to_agg_upon":["0","1","2","5","4"],
"value_to_copy":["a","b","c","d","e"]})

df_numeric = df.copy()

df_numeric["value_to_agg_upon"] = pd.to_numeric(df_numeric["value_to_agg_upon"])

df.iloc[df_numeric.groupby("value_to_groupby")["value_to_agg_upon"].idxmin(), 1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: value_to_agg_upon should be obviously local min and not global min. Changed example to clarify.

Comment: @NoaYehezkel the new answer should provide a correct answer while taking care of the local/global minima issues.

Comment: Strange thing is when I tried with  the pd.to_numeric it didn't work. But the same code works now :/ : https://snipboard.io/gRvo1J.jpg

Comment: @Pygirl provide me with your name and delete the comment once u receive my invitation